# how do i get an always changing value from a string c#

Tags: c#, string, world-of-warcraft

I am working on a program that will automatically get your characters stats and whatnot from the wow armory. I already have the html, and i can identify where the string is, but i need to get the "this.effective" value, which in this case is 594. But since its always changing (and so are the other values, i cant just take it a certain position. Any help would GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks

Matt
---------      This is the html snippet:

```
    function strengthObject() {
        this.base="168";
        this.effective="594";
        this.block="29";
        this.attack="1168";
```

this.diff=this.effective - this.base;

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using regular expressions:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string html = @"        function strengthObject() {
                this.base=""168"";
                this.effective=""594"";
                this.block=""29"";
                this.attack=""1168"";";

        string regex = @"this.effective=""(\d+)""";

        Match match = Regex.Match(html, regex);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            int effective = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("Effective = " + effective);
            // etc..
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle failure...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this great idea, i never though about using it this way.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to extract the information from the XML version of the website.

If you make a request to a URL like this (Only with a valid character name) then you get back an XML document that you can use an XML parser to easily extract the data.

http://eu.wowarmory.com/character-sheet.xml?r=Nordrassil&cn=Someone

The URLs are the same as the ones you see in your web browser.

Please note though that **you MUST set the User Agent** field of the request to be that of a supported browser that supports the XML version of the file or you get back HTML instead. I use "Mozilla/5.0 Firefox/2.0.0.1" as the user agent in my program and it works fine.

Oh, also don't make more than a few requests in second, or an average of more than one request every 3 or 4 seconds or the site blocks your IP for a few hours ...

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a regular expression to extract this value from the HTML source:

```
this.effective="(\d+)"
```

Note that HTML scraping is not an ideal solution (for example, it may break when the format of the HTML changes) however I don't know about the "wow armory" and what other ways there are to get this information.

Comment: i don't think there are any other ways of retrieving this information programmatic-ly.

Comment: You can get the data as XML documents if you set the user agent